# How and when are interrupt key combination,such as CTRL-C, translated to signals?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, embedded-linux, tty

Using a Linux OS, I need to transparently pass all keystrokes from remote connections to local hardware connections. This is fairly straight forward for everything but signals. I know I can register handlers for each signal that capture and pass the keystroke, but this seems like a hack that might not work for edge cases (what if someone changes the interrupt key combo mapping, would I be double passing the keystrokes, etc.).

In order to come up with a better solution, I really need to know more about how the key combos, IE: CTRL-C, become signals, IE: SIGINT.

1. How does the keycombo become a Signal (in the kernel, client application, runtime)?
2. Is the keystroke still passed? If CTRL-C has a null handler, does STDIN still get CTRL-C?
3. What is the best way to not interpret any keystroke as a signal combination? Can this be done in TTY or Environment settings?

Comment: In short:a signal is not a keystroke.  They are unrelated.

Comment: You want **tcsetattr** (`man 3 termios`) to set the terminal into raw mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The key combo is turned into a signal by the terminal's *line discipline*, a layer in the TTY subsystem. Here's the description [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline):

> For example, the standard line discipline processes the data it receives from the hardware driver and from applications writing to the device according to the requirements of a terminal on a Unix-like system. On input, it handles special characters such as the interrupt character (typically Control-C) and the erase and kill characters (typically backspace or delete, and Control-U, respectively) and, on output, it replaces all the LF characters with a CR/LF sequence.

2. The keypress is not passed, it's suppressed when the signal is raised. If the process has no SIGINT handler, the kernel will terminate it.
3. You can obviously override this: that's how tools like `ssh` work. You can easily do this by setting the terminal to "raw" mode, e.g. with the shell command `stty raw`. If you then run `cat -vE` you can hit any keys you want and see them printed in caret notation. Make sure to plan on a way to close the terminal because you can obviously not Ctrl-C/Z/D out of it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the keycombo become a Signal (in the kernel, client application, runtime)?

This translation is performed as part of [the kernel's TTY line discipline](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial/tty.txt). There are a number of other translations performed as part of this process, like end-of-file (^D), stop signalling (^Z), character echo, basic line editing (backspace, ^U, etc), and DEL/BS and CR/CRLF translation.

> Is the keystroke still passed? If CTRL-C has a null handler, does STDIN still get CTRL-C?

No. Control characters which are handled by the line discipline are not passed to the foreground process.

> What is the best way to not interpret any keystroke as a signal combination? Can this be done in TTY or Environment settings?

Use [`tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr) to change the terminal attributes. The `c_cc` element of `struct termios` contains settings for control characters; you can disable some or all elements by setting them to `_POSIX_VDISABLE`.

(You can also use `cfmakeraw()` -- documented at the same page as above -- to clear most elements of a `struct termios`, giving you a mostly "raw" terminal. However, this may disable more terminal behaviors than you expect.)